# run-program to launch alsaplayer in sbcl

Tags: sbcl

The `sbcl` instruction:
`(run-program "/bin/ls" '() :output *standard-output*)` 
works fine on my box *:squeeze* _Debian_. However I can't run :

`(run-program "/usr/bin/alsaplayer CD.cdda" '()  :output :stream)`

I think that `:out :stream` option is not aproppiate for this case, but can someone tell me what are the good  options ?

Thanks in advance.

Gérard

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in the output, try

```
(run-program "/usr/bin/alsaplayer" '("CD.cdda"))
```

or, if you still want to use your lisp repl while the music is playing,

```
(run-program "/usr/bin/alsaplayer" '("CD.cdda") :wait nil)
```

See [SBCL Manual Sec. 7.4.3 Running external programs](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs).

Also, include some output/error message so that people can better diagnose the problem.

Comment: for the second :(run-program "/usr/bin/alsaplayer"  '("-q" "CD.cdda") :wait nil)