# Accessing custom bash script from SBCL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443748/run-program-to-launch-alsaplayer-in-sbcl) but it doesn't seem to apply here.

Using SBCL, this works fine:

`(run-program "/bin/ls" () :output *standard-output*)`

So does this:

`(run-program "/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari" ())`

It launches a Safari window.

I can create a bash script in my `bin` directory that just has this in it:

`/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`

When I run this bash script from the Terminal, Safari opens.

But I cannot run this script from inside SBCL:

`(run-program "/Users/myhome/bin/safariscript" ())`

REPL reports:

```
Couldn't execute "/Users/myhome/bin/safariscript": Exec format error
[Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

The script certainly works fine on its own. I've searched ad nauseum for the meaning of this error without any help that would apply to a lisp environment, so I wonder if there is a broader issue at play here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell scripts need a [shell-bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line in it in order to be run via `execve` or anything that uses it, such as `run-program`. So you should use this as your file's content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Comment: @OpenLearner And the reason it works from the shell is that it will helpfully (or maybe "helpfully") see the error from exec and instead go "I know, let's exec my own path, with the script's path as the first argument!". And then it looks like everything is fine, but in fact it isn't.